# Turn a single number into single digits Python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to make a number , for example 43365644 into single numbers [4,3,3....,4,4]

and append it on a list

Answer (score 117):

This can be done quite easily if you:

1. Use [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) to convert the number into a string so that you can iterate over it.
2. Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to split the string into individual digits.
3. Use [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int) to convert the digits back into integers.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> n = 43365644
>>> [int(d) for d in str(n)]
[4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: This is not valid in case of a negative integer.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a way to do it without turning it into a string first (based on some rudimentary benchmarking, this is about twice as fast as stringifying `n` first):

```
>>> n = 43365644
>>> [(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 10))-1, -1, -1)]
[4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4]
```

Updating this after many years in response to comments of this not working for powers of 10:

```
[(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 10)), -1, -1)][bool(math.log(n,10)%1):]
```

The issue is that with powers of 10 (and ONLY with these), an extra step is required. ---So we use the remainder in the log_10 to determine whether to remove the leading `0`--- We can't exactly use this because floating-point math errors cause this to fail for some powers of 10. So I've decided to cross the unholy river into sin and call upon regex.

```
In [32]: n = 43

In [33]: [(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 10)), -1, -1)][not(re.match('10*', str(n))):]
Out[33]: [4, 3]

In [34]: n = 1000

In [35]: [(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 10)), -1, -1)][not(re.match('10*', str(n))):]
Out[35]: [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I guess there is a cross point where calculating an arbitrarily big power of 10 will cost more than parsing a string per each digit. I did not look into this, though :)

Comment: This is basically what the `str` function has to do internally as well, it doesn't just magically have the string representation. Of course the built-in `str` function is written in C and therefore faster than Python code, but I'm pretty sure the numbers would have to get extremely big for this to be slower than parsing a string as the Python interpreter can heavily optimize list comprehensions. Additionally you could use this as an iterator if you don't really need a list, improving performance further, whereas the `str` function will always build the complete string at a time.

Comment: @Cu3PO42: You do have a point. Perhaps it is the stringification and re-intification that causes the 2x runtime (2 conversions, which are effectively inverses of each other, in some ways). Also, let's not forget that the built-in math is also implemented in C, which should be comparably fast, in context

Comment: Wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Pasting your two lines into a python shell (2.7.10), with an `import math` first, gives me: `TypeError: range() integer start argument expected, got float.`

Comment: @melwil: surround that `math.ceil` with an `int(...)` inside the call to `range`. That should fix it

Comment: This answer gives incorrect results for powers of 10. For example, it returns `[0, 0]` when `n == 100`.

Comment: How could be possible to get many upvotes in this answer!? This gives wrong results for any input in the set {1, 10,100, 1000, etc}.

Comment: @JackMeister is right, this is not working for powers of 10. I'm trying to resolve myself but I wonder why is it not resolved at all by the poster.

Comment: Updated my answer after 7 years :) 
Thanks for the feedback, folks!

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thank you for the update! Sadly it does not work for 1000 now. Works for 1, 10, 100 and 10000. Also not working for 1 million, so every 10**3 steps the leading 1 cuts off.

Comment: @MattSom: Oh! FML! `math.log(1000, 10)` gives 2.99999...8 rather than 3

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Haha I see. So need the second ceiling func for the additional log func?

Comment: @MattSom: can't use a `ceil` to fix that. I've done something dastardly with `re`. Here comes

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I see, I'll try to decipher it to understand. I wonder, is the benchmark still considerably better this way?

Comment: @MattSom: I actually wonder if "the correct answer" will end up being `while n: answer.append(n%10); n//=10`

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to turn the int into a string and take each character of the string as an element of your list:

```
>>> n = 43365644 
>>> digits = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
>>> digits
[4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4]
>>> lst.extend(digits)  # use the extends method if you want to add the list to another
```

It involves a casting operation, but it's readable and acceptable if you don't need extreme performance.

Comment: it does not work with negatives

Comment: @DAG What could be the expected result for `-123`? `[-1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 2, 3]`? Or even `[-1, -2, -3]`? We could dismiss the minus sign in the string by doing `str(n).strip('-')` but the negative case was not given in the original question.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change your number into a list of those numbers, I would first cast it to a `string`, then casting it to a list will naturally break on each character:

```
[int(x) for x in str(n)]
```