# Split integer into digits using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a question. The question is asked before but as far as i can see never using numpy.
I want split a value in the different digits. do somthing and return back into a number. based on the questions below i can do what i want.
But i prefere to do it all in numpy. I expect it is more efficient because i'm not changing back and forward to numpy arrays.
See example:

Example:

```
import numpy as np


l = np.array([43365644])  # is input array
n = int(43365644)
m = [int(d) for d in str(n)]
o = np.aslist(np.sort(np.asarray(m)))
p = np.asarray(''.join(map(str,o)))
```

I have tried serval times but without much luck.
I had one moment i used the split function and it worked (in the terminal) but after add it to a script it failed again and i was unable to reproduce what i did before..

`q = np.sort(np.split(l,1),axis=1)`
no error but it is still a singel value.

`q = np.sort(np.split(l,8),axis=1)`
With this method it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

Is there some way that this is possible in numpy? thanks in advance

referenced questions:
[Turn a single number into single digits Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270320/turn-a-single-number-into-single-digits-python#21270338)
[Convert list of ints to one number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number#490020)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

1. Divide your number by 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... rounding down
2. Modulo the result by 10

which yields

```
l // 10 ** np.arange(10)[:, None] % 10
```

Or if you want a solution that works for

- any base
- any number of digits and
- any number of dimensions

you can do

```
l = np.random.randint(0, 1000000, size=(3, 3, 3, 3))
l.shape
# (3, 3, 3, 3)

b = 10                                                   # Base, in our case 10, for 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...
n = np.ceil(np.max(np.log(l) / np.log(b))).astype(int)   # Number of digits
d = np.arange(n)                                         # Divisor base b, b ** 2, b ** 3, ...
d.shape = d.shape + (1,) * (l.ndim)                      # Add dimensions to divisor for broadcasting
out = l // b ** d % b

out.shape
# (6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```