# apply custom function in numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, filter

I have a list,

```
mylist=np.array([120,3,10,33,5,54,2,23,599,801])
```

and a function:

```
def getSum(n): 
    n=n**2
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0): 

        sum = sum + int(n % 10) 
        n = int(n/10) 
    if sum <20:
        return True
    return False
```

I am trying to apply my function to mylist and retrive only those indices are true.

my expected output is.

```
[120, 3, 10, 33, 5, 54, 2, 23, 801]
```

I can do that like `list(filter(getSum,mylist))`, how to use it in numpy.

tried `np.where` not producing the expected output.

Comment: Your function will not work and throws errors at while loop. Can you explain the logic that exactly you want to implement using `numpy`. That could help to understand the problem.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, i found it, we need `np.vectorize`, I will add answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the sums of the digits are `> 20`, here a pure `numpy` solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040682/split-integer-into-digits-using-numpy) can find how to decompose an integer in its digits):

```
import numpy as np


mylist=np.array([120,3,10,33,5,54,2,23,599,801])

mylist = mylist**2
max_digits = np.ceil(np.max(np.log10(mylist)))  # max number of digits in mylist
digits = mylist//(10**np.arange(max_digits)[:, None])%10  # matrix of digits
digitsum = np.sum(digits, axis=0)  # array of sums
mask = digitsum < 20
mask
# array([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True])
```

**Update: speed comparison**

@hpaulj does a nice time comparison among (almost) all proposed solutions.
Winner was `filter` with a pure `list` input, while my *pure numpy* solution did not performed well.
Anyway, if we test them against a wider range of inputs, things change.
Here's a test performed with [perflot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) from @NicoSchlömer.
For input of 100+ elements all solutions are equivalent, while pure numpy is faster:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there are loops, so better here is use `numba`:

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def get_vals(arr):
    out = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    for i, n in enumerate(arr):

        n=n**2
        sum1 = 0
        while (n != 0): 
            sum1 = sum1 + int(n % 10) 
            n = int(n/10) 
        if sum1 <20:
            out[i] = True
    return arr[out]

print(get_vals(mylist))
```

Comment: jezrael ,  thank you. what do you think about my np.vectorize, which one is efficient?

Comment: @pyd - I think `np.vectorized` should be slowier, the best test in real data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension`, the underlying concept of [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is for loop from the documents (also doesn't improve your performance):

```
mylist[[getSum(i) for i in mylist]]

array([120,   3,  10,  33,   5,  54,   2,  23, 801])
```

Answer (score 1):

The function and test array:

```
In [22]: def getSum(n):  
    ...:     n=n**2 
    ...:     sum = 0 
    ...:     while (n != 0):  
    ...:  
    ...:         sum = sum + int(n % 10)  
    ...:         n = int(n/10)  
    ...:     if sum <20: 
    ...:         return True 
    ...:     return False 
    ...:                                                                        
In [23]: mylist=np.array([120,3,10,33,5,54,2,23,599,801])
```

Your `filter` solution:

```
In [51]: list(filter(getSum, mylist))                                           
Out[51]: [120, 3, 10, 33, 5, 54, 2, 23, 801]
```

and a sample timing:

```
In [52]: timeit list(filter(getSum, mylist))                                    
32.8 µs ± 185 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Since this returns a list, and iterates, it should be faster if `mylist` was a list, rather than an array:

```
In [53]: %%timeit alist=mylist.tolist() 
    ...: list(filter(getSum, alist))                                                                        
18.4 µs ± 378 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

### alternatives

You proposed use of **`np.vectorize`**:

```
In [56]: f = np.vectorize(getSum); mylist[f(mylist)]                            
Out[56]: array([120,   3,  10,  33,   5,  54,   2,  23, 801])
In [57]: timeit f = np.vectorize(getSum); mylist[f(mylist)]                     
63.4 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [58]: timeit mylist[f(mylist)]                                               
57.6 µs ± 920 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Oops! that's quite a bit slower, even if we remove the `f` creation from the timing loop.  `vectorize` is pretty, but does not promise speed.

I've found that **`frompyfunc`** is faster than `np.vectorize` (though they are related):

```
In [59]: g = np.frompyfunc(getSum, 1,1)                                         
In [60]: g(mylist)                                                              
Out[60]: 
array([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True],
      dtype=object)
```

the result is object dtype, which in this case has to be converted to bool:

```
In [63]: timeit mylist[g(mylist).astype(bool)]                                  
25.5 µs ± 233 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

That's better than your `filter` - but only if applied to the array, not the list.

`@Saandeep` proposed a **list comprehension**:

```
In [65]: timeit mylist[[getSum(i) for i in mylist]]                             
40.7 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

That's a bit slower than your `filter`.

A faster way to use list comprehension is:

```
 [i for i in mylist if getSum(i)]
```

This times the same as your `filter` - for both the array and list versions (I lost the session where I was timing things).

### pure numpy

`@lante` worked out a pure `numpy` solution, clever but a bit obscure.  I haven't worked out the logic:

```
def lante(mylist):
    max_digits = np.ceil(np.max(np.log10(mylist)))  # max number of digits in mylist
    digits = mylist//(10**np.arange(max_digits)[:, None])%10  # matrix of digits
    digitsum = np.sum(digits, axis=0)  # array of sums
    mask = digitsum > 20
    return mask
```

And unfortunately not a speed demon:

```
In [69]: timeit mylist[~lante(mylist)]                                          
58.9 µs ± 757 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I don't have `numba` installed, so can't time `@jezrael's` solution.

So your original `filter` is a good solution, especially if you start with a list rather than an array.  Especially when considering conversion times, a good Python list solution is often better than `numpy` one.

Timings may be different with a large example, but I don't expect any upsets.

Comment: nice comparison. but I suggest you to try with large samples. You'll be surprised by the upsets (not here to start a speed war). also a 100 numbers list I guess

Comment: @LanteDellarovere, your solution does scale better - but for some reason doesn't produce the same result for big array like `blist=np.random.randint(1,1000,10000) `

Comment: I just noticed that OP sums digits of squared elements (not original from `mylist`), and also test if are `<20` (not `>20` as I did). Edited.  A plus time for `mylist**2` creation has to be added, but still numpy version will be much faster.

Comment: If you are interested, I extended your time comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
vec=np.vectorize(getSum)
mylist[vec(mylist)]
out[]:
array([120,   3,  10,  33,   5,  54,   2,  23, 801])
```