# Create numpy array of arrays with leading zeros and different start- and stop-points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, leading-zero, linspace

I have different integer start and stop values and need all integer values in between as arrays in one array of shape (theRange, finalLength).

**Example:**

```
finalLength = 6
start = 2
stop = 3456
theRange = (stop - start) + 1


>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
           ...,
           [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 4],
           [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 5],
           [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

>>> array.shape (3455, 6)
```

As I need to run this function billions of times the current way is to slow.

At the moment I create the desired range using `np.linspace`.
The integers are split into digits following ([Split integer into digits using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040682/split-integer-into-digits-using-numpy).

If the number of digits of the largest number is not equal to finalLength, leading zeros are added.
Finally, the resulting array is flipped and transposed to the desired output format.
I think the integer splitting and transposing takes the most computation time.

> **Time increases with longer finalLength: Timeit 10000 reps**
>
> finalLength =  6 --> time: 2.815263898999546
>
> finalLength = 12 --> time: 4.158567378000043
>
> finalLength = 24 --> time: 5.038266787999419

Is there a faster way to create the final array?

**Reproducable code:**

```
import numpy as np

finalLength = 6
start = 2
stop = 3456
theRange = (stop - start) + 1

def makeRangeArray(start, stop, theRange, finalLength):
    # create integers within range
    ll = np.array(np.linspace(start=start, stop=stop, num=theRange), dtype=np.int64)

    # split integers into arrays
    b = 10
    n = np.ceil(np.max(np.log(ll) / np.log(b))).astype(np.int64)
    d = np.arange(n)
    d.shape = d.shape + (1,) * ll.ndim
    out = ll // b ** d % b

    # add leading zeros if necessary
    if finalLength - out.shape[0] != 0:
        addZeros = np.zeros([finalLength - out.shape[0], out.shape[1]], dtype=np.int64)
        out = np.append(out, addZeros, axis=0)  # insert zeros at the end of array

    # flip
    out = np.flip(out, axis=0)

    # transpose to desired final output format
    aaa = out.transpose().reshape((theRange, finalLength))

    return aaa
```

Comment: _As I need to run this function billions of times the current way is to slow._ I think your best bet is to find a way to not have to run anything billions of times, assuming that we're talking about a relatively short timespan, of course.

Comment: To add to AMC's comment, if the same array is used every time, then generate once and use it as a global variable or pass the array between functions. If you need suggestions on how to optimise your workflow, then you can open another question.

Comment: I want to create all possible combinations of numbers for a certain word length, e.g. 16 digits numbers with charset 0-9 will result in possible 10.000.000.000.000.000 combinations. To use np.unique() to filter for target combinations, e.g. discard all combinations having more than 8 duplicate digits, I need the number as arrays. Due to memory and cpu limitations I want to work with chunks of data. Hence, working with so many combinations to filter will result in billions of chunks. I am trying different approaches but until now I could not figure out one way that is fast enough.