# How to split list based on characters and then make sub-lists?

Tags: python, list

How do I split a list into sub-lists, and then further split that to make each character an independent value?

I need to do this all inside of Python, version 3.6.5. The list will be in integers.

I need to convert

```
[123, 456]
```

into

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

**EDIT:**

And after I have done that, how do I print the first character of the first sublist?

> Note: [Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python) and [Turn a single number into single digits Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270320/turn-a-single-number-into-single-digits-python) don't solve *or* answer my problem, as they do not explain how to make sub-lists out of them.

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python). Sometimes, a little search helps and is quicker than posting question which shows no research effort and no attempt like yours

Comment: *"they do not explain how to make sub-lists"* - so what? They show you how to process one number, so then you just need to apply the same logic to each of them in the list.

Comment: What have *you tried* to get the first character of the first sub list, and what is the problem with it? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered and you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, using `list comprehension`:-

```
my_list = ['123', '456']
[list(x) for x in my_list]
```

If `my_list` is a list of integers:-

```
my_list = [123, 456]
[[int(x) for x in str(n)] for n in my_list]
```

Comment: `my_list = ['123', '456']`? The OP never said that the input is strings. Why are you making this assumption out of nowhere? You should add explanation similar to "If my_list is a list of integers-" for strings

Comment: Please see my full answer

Comment: Will this divide them into sub-lists though?

Comment: @ArihanSharma-SirJohnAMac: Try the code and check the output

Comment: yes it will, I suggest reading more about list comprehension - https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Checked, it just outputs `[123, 456]`.

Comment: Did you check my_list or did you check the output? (it does not assign the result to any variable)

Comment: @TomRon You forgot to re-assign `my_list`.

Comment: @TomRon Also: This takes a lot of time. Is there a faster way?

Comment: It is your call what to do with the result. I have to think regarding faster way but not sure I have the time to compare several implementations

Comment: @TomRon Now how do I print the first character of the first sublist?

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension will do, the idea is iterate over the characters in the string representation of the numbers:

```
[[int(x) for x in str(s)] for s in l]
```

Comment: Will this divide them into sub-lists though?

Comment: @ArihanSharma-SirJohnAMac, Indeed, that is why we have a list within the list.

Comment: Now how do I print the first character of the first sublist?