# Python String to array in form

Tags: python

I cant create like `[12,34,56,78]`

I tried used list(),but can't get the answer.

```
A=12345678,list(A)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

i need the result like `12345678=[12,34,56,78]`.Any answer?

Comment: `[int(str(A)[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(str(A)), 2)]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270320/turn-a-single-number-into-single-digits-python

Comment: MelKoutch - it’s different format

Comment: How is this a different format ? Because it's a pair of number instead of single digits ? Please, explain clearly your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
s = '12345678'
n = 2
result=[s[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
print(result)

['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

Comment: Yes,you are right.

Comment: The output from this snippet is wrong, it'd be `['12', '34', '56', '78']` instead and not `[12, 34, 56, 78]` since you are not converting them to int.

Comment: @ DirtyBit thank to point my typo error,

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
A = '12345678'

print([int(A[x:x+2]) for x in range(0, len(A), 2)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78]
```