# reorder digits of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Suppose I have an integer (say `235`) and I want to reorder this number in all possible ways and get all other integers in a list or tuple. Is there a way to do it in python?
The desired output will consist of: `[235, 253, 325, 352, 523, 532]`

And any other if I missed some.

I wanna create a list tuple or any other thing of all these values from where I can use these values somewhere else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn a single number into single digits Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270320/turn-a-single-number-into-single-digits-python)

Comment: I would suggest turning the number into a string and using itertools permutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.permutation`, one-liners are good to show that you know python very well, but what actually matters is the maintainability. Here is a maintainable code, where every function is doing a single work and after reading the code we can get the logic(wherein the case of a one-liner, we need to spend time understanding the code):

```
from itertools import permutations as perm

def to_int(p):
    return int(''.join(map(str, p)))

def all_perms(n):
    digits = list(map(int, str(n)))
    perms = []
    for p in perm(digits, len(digits)):
        perms.append(to_int(p))
    return perms

n = 235
print(all_perms(n))
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert number into list of string numbers then do permutations.

```
import itertools
number = 235
results = [int("".join(x)) for x in list(itertools.permutations(list(str(number))))]
```

Output:

```
[235, 253, 325, 352, 523, 532]
```

Comment: Don't you think one-liners are not good for maintenance purposes? I learned here that one-liners are not good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the number to a string, then use a list comprehension to extract each digit as a character.  This gives you the list of digit strings, e.g. `['2', '3', '5']`.

Use `permutations` to get the different arrangements, joining the result and converting them back to integers.

```
from itertools import permutations

integer = 235
numbers = [i for i in str(integer)]  # ['2', '3', '5']

>>> list(int(''.join(p)) for p in permutations(numbers))
[235, 253, 325, 352, 523, 532]

# Or just simply (no need for `numbers`):
# list(int(''.join(p)) for p in permutations(str(integer)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.permutations:

```
import itertools
list(map(int,map("".join,itertools.permutations("235"))))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations